# Delete element in array from Local storage via input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, input, local-storage

I have an array saved in localstorage and trying to delete an element onclick based on input value. I have the code below but I cant make it work. Please help, Thanks in advance :)

```
var datarray = [];

function deldata() {

  // retrieve stored data (JSON stringified) and convert
  var storedData = localStorage.getItem("list_data_key");
  if (storedData) {
    datarray = JSON.parse(storedData);
  }


var titleValue = document.getElementById('listxt').value;
// Find and remove item from an array
var i = array.indexOf(titleValue);
if(i != -1) {
    array.splice(i, 1);
}
localStorage.setItem("list_data_key", JSON.stringify(datarray));
  datapost();
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JCprog/115Lsk7L/33/)

Comment: you're not using function `deldata`...? And you're using `JSON.stringify(datarray)` but changing `data`. Please rethink your question and try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change**

```
var i = array.indexOf(titleValue);
if(i > -1) {
    array.splice(i, 1);
}
```

**to**

```
var i = datarray.indexOf(titleValue);
if(i > -1) {
    datarray.splice(i, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Watch your variable names.

```
function deldata() {
  // retrieve stored data (JSON stringified) and convert
  var storedData = localStorage.getItem("list_data_key");
  if (storedData) {
    datarray = JSON.parse(storedData);
  }

  var titleValue = document.getElementById('listxt').value;
  // Find and remove item from an array
  var i = datarray.indexOf(titleValue);  //  HERE  (was 'array')
  if(i != -1) {
    datarray.splice(i, 1);  //  HERE  (was 'array')
  }
  localStorage.setItem("list_data_key", JSON.stringify(datarray));
  datapost();
}
```